# Runas different user to launch CMD and run command

Tags: windows, command-line

I want to run a batch file as a different user, via the `Windows -> Run` dialogue.

I have tried:

```
runas /profile /user:test CMD "C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\Run.bat"

runas /profile /user:test "CMD "C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\Run.bat""

runas /profile /user:test "CMD \"C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\Run.bat\""

runas /profile /user:test "CMD \"C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\Run.bat"\"
```

but still no luck. It opens up CMD and asks me for my password. I enter it, and it opens another CMD window using the other username, **but** it doesn't run the bat. Instead, the title bar just says

> Administrator: cmd "C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\Run.bat" (running as Home-PC\test)

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Do you want to run this as a one-time thing, or something repeatedly for different users?

Comment: I would like to run this as the system administrator, once a day. the batch file reaches out to a server to get updates for a program that I have.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a switch. From `CMD /?`:

```
/C      Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates
/K      Carries out the command specified by string but remains
```

These commands should work. Choose the one that suits your needs.

```
runas /profile /user:test "CMD /C C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\Run.bat"

runas /profile /user:test "CMD /K C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\Run.bat"
```

If the path contains spaces, surround it with escaped double quotes (`\"`):

```
runas /profile /user:test "CMD /C \"C:\Users\My Name\Desktop\Run.bat\""

runas /profile /user:test "CMD /K \"C:\Users\My Name\Desktop\Run.bat\""
```

Comment: @EricK. Did it work for you? If so, it'd be great if you mark this as the answer so we know that a solution found :)

Comment: These instructions are wrong.  You cannot specify any arguments to the program you wish to run with `runas`.  More information [here](http://superuser.com/a/560641/156601).

Comment: @NicoleHamilton: My syntax was wrong (I only focused on the missing switch), but you *can* pass arguments to the command. `runas /?` actually shows two examples. I've tested the two commands in my (edited) answer, and they work.

Comment: Okay, I agree, that fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be exactly what you want, but you can launch a command with **admin** rights by hitting `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` on the Run dialog

[image]

Comment: I thought Ctrl+Shift+Enter only worked in the search. I will check out if it works for run too, I wish I knew this before!!