# Possible to continue runas /u:domain\admin cmd with followup commands in the new CMD window?

Tags: command-line, remote-control, runas, remote-assistance

Is it possible to continue `runas /u:domain\admin` command with followup commands in a new CMD.EXE window?

I tried this but it didn't work: [Runas different user to launch CMD and run command](https://superuser.com/questions/417351/runas-different-user-to-launch-cmd-and-run-command)

What I want is to run `msra /offerra` using CMD.EXE, however I need to first run CMD as another user with admin privileges using `runas` as shown above.

Comment: My commands had a syntax error. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Those instructions](https://superuser.com/a/417354/156601) were wrong and have been fixed.  Here's the usage for `runas`:

```
RUNAS USAGE:

RUNAS [ [/noprofile | /profile] [/env] [/savecred | /netonly] ]
        /user:<UserName> program

RUNAS [ [/noprofile | /profile] [/env] [/savecred] ]
        /smartcard [/user:<UserName>] program

RUNAS /trustlevel:<TrustLevel> program
```

Notice that in all three variations, you can specify only a program to be run, nothing else.  They mean it:  *You cannot specify any arguments to the program as separate words.*  Any arguments must be embedded into the "program" string with surrounding quotes.

Also not made clear is that `runas` will not pass the current directories; it always starts in  `C:\Windows\System32`.  So any program you specify must either be in a `PATH` directory or given as a full path.  You cannot use a relative path.  And of course, any ACLs on that executable or the directories on its path must allow access by the user you'd like to run it as.

The good news is that `runas` will accept a `.cmd` file as a "program".

As a practical matter, what this means is that to do what you want, you'll probably want to create a `.cmd` file in a directory both users can access, then pass the full path.  For example:

```
runas /u:Fred "C:\Users\Public\foo.cmd"
```

The final wrinkle is that `runas` can start a program as another user, but it can't elevate.  There's no way to cause it to generate the UAC prompt.  If you'd like to run something "as administrator" using `runas`, you'll have to [enable the builtin Administrator account](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744293(v=ws.10).aspx), which always runs elevated anyway, and specify that user name.

If that's not going to work for you and you need a generalized ability to pass arguments and/or current directories or if you need to run something elevated as something other than Administrator, you'll need a genuine `su`, like [this one](http://hamiltonlabs.com/UserGuide/Utilities/su.htm).

Answer (score 3):

This is what you would need to put into the BAT command:

C:\windows\system32\runas.exe /u:domain\username "cmd /c Start /B %windir%\system32\msra.exe /offerra"

Comment: Wau....it sure works...no elevation